# What would the the RegEx sequence to replace all the substrings before the pattern?

Tags: python, regex, replace

This is the text string.

> "9020  >  49784 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450"

I want to remove all the parts of the substring before Seq= part. I have thought of using .sub function of RegEx in Python but cannot formulate the pattern. The pattern should be every character or number would be selected until Seq= comes.

Sample Code:

```
import re

#I want to remove everything that comes before "Seq=" part using Regex

txt = "9020  >  49784 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450"
x = re.compile(???)
txt = regex.sub("Seq=",txt)
```

What should be the pattern in the ??? position of x=re.compile(???) part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern `.*?Seq=` and replace it by `Seq=`. The pattern will match everything till the first occurrence of `Seq=`

```py
pattern = re.compile(".*?Seq=")
txt = pattern.sub('Seq=',txt)

#output: Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450"
```

You can also use lookahead assertion `.*?(?=Seq=)`, and replace the match by empty string `''`:

```py
>>> re.sub('.*?(?=Seq=)','', txt)
'Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use regex for this? It looks like a simple enough problem to be solved with `str`'s methods. Here's a quick-n-dirty approach

```py
>>> txt = "9020  >  49784 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450"
>>> txt[txt.index("Seq=1")+5:]
' Ack=1 Win=1869 Len=1388 TSval=467182 TSecr=366189450'
```

The `index` method searches for a given string and returns its index, if found. Then, you can just play with it.